# Innovative ways of designing disclosures for financial products

Tags: financial

I'm looking to see if there are some different ways of moving users through several disclosures on financial products: personal loans, credit credit cards, etc. We currently employ individual checkboxes for each one, but I wanted to see if we could do something a bit more innovative.

Are there some interesting examples that folks could share, and maybe some pros/cons for the differing implementations?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to sections of a document that would be initialed if it were on paper? A concrete example would be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you with the ***token input functionality***.

PROS

- Increases the efficiency of the data usage in long term.
- Makes the users to be more conscious of they require.

As in-case of the check box functionality the user tends to check all boxes *(responsive time of the user for the check box is less as compared to the token input)* which may be unnecessary for the user which causes the data usage more.

CONS

- User must have the knowledge of what they require.
- Time consumption is bit more incase of the token input as compared to check box.

[image: Token-input functionality]